# $H^0_c (X_{et}, \mathscr{F}) = 0$ for any affine smooth curve $X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $X$ an affine connected smooth $k$ curve, and $\mathscr{F}$ a locally constant sheaf on $X_{et}$.
Then $H^0_c (X,  \mathscr{F}) = 0$?
(This is 2.10.(a) of Deligne's Weil I)

To show this, I showed:

> Let $X$ be an irreducible scheme, $j : U \to X$ an open immersion such that $U \neq X$, and $\mathscr{F}$ be a locally constant sheaf on $U$. Then $\Gamma(X, j_! \mathscr{F}) = 0$.

I think that what I want to show originally (i.e., 2.10.(a) of Deligne) follows form this, since for a compactification $j : X \to \overline{X}$, we have $H^0_c(X, \mathscr{F}) = \Gamma(\overline{X}, j_!\mathscr{F})$.
Is my opinion true?
I'm not confident about it because in this "proof" I used only $X \neq \overline{X}$, and did not use the affineness and smoothness of $X$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Recall that a non proper curve is affine so this affineness assumption is not really strong. The smoothness is indeed more intriguing. I believe it is here just to explain this statement in light of the Poincaré duality.

Comment: @Roland So, do you think that we don't need the smoothness in 2.10.(a) but we do in 2.10.(b)?

Comment: Yes probably, I strongly believe your highlight claim is true, but maybe you can put your proof of it (I did not have time to think about it). There is also the remark "Assertion (i) simply means that $\mathscr{F}$ does not have sections with finite support", which also goes in this direction.